# Find the sum of the following series $-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following series $$-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{81}-\frac{1}{324}+\dots$$

Comment: This is a quintessential example of a geometric series...  or wait... it would have been if you were talking about the series that you typed.  You have a typo and forgot the $\frac{1}{n}$.  It will still converge regardless, you should be able to use alternating series test or abels test to show this, or to show it is absolutely convergent first by a comparison test

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and so integrating both sides gives $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = -\ln (1-x)$. Substituting $x = -\frac{1}{3}$ therefore gives the answer $\ln(\frac{4}{3}) = \ln 4 - \ln 3$.

Comment: $\ln(3)-\ln(2)\approx .4054$.  But the sum of this series (with alternating terms) should be less than $\frac13$.

Comment: @paw88789 The answer is $\displaystyle\ln\left(\,{4 \over 3}\,\right) \approx 0.2877 \color{red}{< {1 \over 3}}$.

Comment: gah sorry i had no idea what i was thinking, it's way too late here